# Is it possible to change the way my data is currently displayed?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, row, cellrenderer

I am using a JTable and after it is filled with data, I have a search button at the bottom with a text input. Once I type in "Joe" it brings up all of joes details. However, these are displayed in one row going left to right (much like a spreadsheet row).

I was wondering if there was a way I can make it display this data in a different way? More like a table rather than going across in one individual row...

Please tell me if I need to show parts of my code as it is quite a bit and I'm unsure if I should paste it all in or not. (New to this site).

Thanks.

Code:

private void makeframe()

```
   {
   frame = new JFrame("Search");
   frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
   Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
   contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
   }

   DefaultTableModel  model = new DefaultTableModel();
   model.addColumn("User");
   model.addColumn("first name");
   model.addColumn("surname");
//this goes on for a while

     model.addRow(data);
   JTable mainTable = new JTable(model);
   contentPane.add(new JScrollPane (mainTable));

  frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1300, 200));
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
```

Comment: It would help if you posted a relevant sample of your source code.

Comment: makeFrame:
 frame = new JFrame("Search");
       frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
       Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
       contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                    
       DefaultTableModel  model = new DefaultTableModel();
       model.addColumn("UserID");
       model.addColumn("Surname");
       model.addColumn("First Name");
.......
 model.addRow(data);
       JTable mainTable = new JTable(model);
       contentPane.add(new JScrollPane (mainTable));

Comment: Edit your post and paste the codes that you have posted in comment to the post ..

Comment: You could use a CardLayout to switch the JTable with a "Search results" panel (assuming that you have a single result). Alternatively, you could provide a details panel, limiting what you display in the table and highlighting the details when the user selects a row

Comment: Thats exactly how it currently works. The rows only display 6 things, however originally when I add a user around 12 things are entered. How would I go about showing this details panel?

Comment: `these are displayed in one row going left to right (much like a spreadsheet row).` for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create your panel in  format you prefer, then use table with only 1 column. Place your pannel inside this column.